# @Autowired or constructor inject non-managed classes into Spring context @Service for better testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

In a Spring Boot project, we access our non managed DAO classes through a static method:

```
MyDao myDao = DaoProvider.getMyDao();
```

We use this in Spring managed `@Service` classes:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    
    public void foo() {
        MyDao myDao = DaoProvider.getMyDao();
        myDao.bar();
        ....
    }
}
```

This makes it hard to write unit tests. Static mocks are no option, because they are slowing down our build pipeline.

We would rather have a solution with `@Autowired` or constructor dependency and some kind of configuration, that decides which class to inject:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    
    @Autowired
    MyDao myDao;
    
    public void foo() {
        myDao.bar();
        ....
    }
}
```

Obviously, someone has to tell Spring what class to inject, because `MyDao` is no Spring managed bean. Is there a way to do so?:

```
@Configuration
public class NonManagedSpringInjectionConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    MyDao getMyDao() {
        return DaoProvider.getMyDao();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `someone has to tell Spring what class to inject` ? Spring automatically inject everything if @Autowire, @Service and @Bean are used correctly

Comment: MyDao is not a Spring managed bean. So Spring won't be able to detect it out of the box. Thank you for the hin, I have edited the question.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, thanks for asking. I did not know you can pretty much register any class as a bean, as describeld in option 2 in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

If you don't want to turn your `MyDao` into a Spring-managed Bean, your simpler and probably best option is to instead create the `MyService` Spring-managed Bean programmatically instead of relying on `@Service` annotation. First, just remove `@Service` from `MyService` and adjust its constructor to accept `MyDao`:

```java
public class MyService {

    MyDao myDao;

    public MyService(MyDao myDao) {
        this.myDao = myDao;
    }
    
    public void foo() {
        myDao.bar();
        ....
    }
}
```

And now you just need to register a `MyService` bean using `@Bean` in a Configuration class as follows:

```java
@Configuration
public class WhateverConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    MyService myService() {
        return new MyService(DaoProvider.getMyDao());
    }
}
```

---

### Option 2

If instead there is a possibility to make `MyDao` a Spring-managed Bean, then just keep your `NonManagedSpringInjectionConfiguration` as is:

```java
@Configuration
public class NonManagedSpringInjectionConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    MyDao getMyDao() {
        return DaoProvider.getMyDao();
    }
}
```

But then rely on constructor injection instead of on `@Autowired`. It makes `MyService` easier to unit test and also explicitly defines that `MyDao` is mandatory for `MyService` to work properly. In this case you would keep `@Service` and rely on Spring to instantiate it:

```java
@Service
public class MyService {

    MyDao myDao;

    public MyService(MyDao myDao) {
        this.myDao = myDao;
    }

    public void foo() {
        myDao.bar();
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to specify the profil for example :

```
@Configuration
public class NonManagedSpringInjectionConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    @Profile("dev")
    MyDao getMyDao() {
        return DaoProvider.getMyDao();
    }
}
```